# Need help to make a simple dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I need a simple dictionary which works like this: first it takes the number of words(n) which we have the translations in 4 languages, then we enter on each line (totally n line) the words we have with their translations seperarated by space as dictionary source, then we need to ask user to enter a phrase which might have more than words it was provided before as dictionary source, and the phrase can be in not only one specific language, for example it might be a mix of English, French and German, but we need to translate the phrase to the first language which is Persian in our case, and if there's no translation it will simply print the word itself. so here is the code :

```
def read_dictionary():
for i in range(0, words_num):
    dict_words = str(input())
    words[dict_words.split()[0]] = dict_words.split()[1:]


def translator():
    translation = ""
    input_phrase = str(input("Enter your phrase to translate please: ")).split()
    for word in input_phrase:
        for k, v in words.items():
            if word in v:
                translation += (k + " ")
            else:
                translation += (word + " ")
    print(translation)

words_num = int(input("Enter the number of existing translated words in dictionary: "))
words = {}
read_dictionary()
translator()
```

so here's sample input and desired output:

```
**input:**
Enter the number of existing translated words in dictionary: 
4
man I je ich        
kheili very très sehr
alaghemand interested intéressé interessiert 
barnamenevisi programming laprogrammation Programmierung
Enter your phrase to translate please: 
I am very interested in programming
**output:**
man am kheili alaghemand in barnamenevisi
```

but it output like this instead:

```
man I I I am am am am very kheili very very interested interested alaghemand interested in in in in programming programming programming barnamenevisi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue stems from your `translator()` function.

For each `word` in the `input_phrase`, you iterate through each `k, v` pair in `words.items()`. Good so far.

So what do we want to happen? We want to look through each pair of `k, v` until we find a matching word (in `v`), then (if we do) we want to add the key `k` to the `translation` we're building. If we don't find a matching word, we just add the original `word` value to `translation`.

The problem with your code is that even if you do find a word, you keep looking through the remaining keys in the dictionary. Also, for each key in the dictionary you're either adding it's translation, or the starting `word`, when you should only be adding the base `word` if you don't find a match.

Personally, I would move your inner `for` loop into a new function called `translate_word()` or something similar, but a simple way to fix your `translator()` function without major changes is as follows:

```
def translator():
    translation = ""
    input_phrase = str(input("Enter your phrase to translate please: ")).split()
    for word in input_phrase:
        found = False
        for k, v in words.items():
            if word in v:
                translation += (k + " ")
                found = True
                break
        if not found:
            translation += (word + " ")
    print(translation)
```

In the new `translator()` function, you can see that for each new word, you set a variable `found` to `False`. `found` will represent whether or not you have found a suitable translation in the dictionary.

You'll then iterate through the dictionary. If you find a match, you add `k` to the translation, set `found` to `True` (because you've found a translation), and `break` out of the inner `for` loop.

Once out of the inner `for` loop, you check if you had `found` a translation for `word`. If you did not find a translation, you simply add the `word` to the `translation`.

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed explanations, I will take that translate_word() approach for the inner loop, makes the code much better.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of one dictionary(containing three languages) for each word, you can define a dictionary for each language something like :

```
dct_eng=dict(), dct_frnch=dict() , dct_grmn=dict()
```

key of each dictionary is the first word from input, this key is same for all three and respectively value of each dict will be second and third and forth word rom input
now you can loop through each word and again loop through each value in dictionary to find corresponding keys of value
and finally use found = False mechanism like Kieran Moynihan mentioned to get translation of word or get word itself in case translation does not exist in dictionaries.

```
translation=''
for word in sentence:# sentence is a list of words which user inputs
found=False
for item in words_dct_eng.keys():
    if word== words_dct_eng[item]:
        translate+=str(item)+' '
        found = True
    if word == words_dct_frch[item]:
        translate += str(item) + ' '
        found = True
    if word == words_dct_grmn[item]:
        translate += str(item) + ' '
        found=True
if not found:
    translate += str(word) + ' '
```